# Xamarin forms WebAuthenticator usage

Tags: c#, authentication, xamarin.forms, social-authentication

I'm trying to implement Facebook Auth for Xamarin Forms App.
I'm doing everything like in this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/web-authenticator?tabs=android so I'm using server side auth. Here is my mobile app code:

```
   public class WebAuthViewModel:ObservableObject
    {
        private const string AuthenticationUrl = "https://myapp.com/mobileauth/";

        private string _accessToken = "";
        private bool _isAuthenticated = false;

        public string AuthToken
        {
            get => _accessToken;
            set => SetProperty(ref _accessToken, value);
        }
    
        public ICommand FacebookCommand { get; }

        public WebAuthViewModel()
        {
            FacebookCommand = new Command(async()=>await OnAuthenticate("Facebook"));
        }

        async Task OnAuthenticate(string scheme)
        {
            try
            {
                WebAuthenticatorResult result = null;

                var authUrl = new Uri(AuthenticationUrl + scheme);
                var callbackUrl = new Uri("myapp://");
                result = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(authUrl, callbackUrl);
                
                AuthToken = string.Empty;

                if (result.Properties.TryGetValue("name", out var name) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                {
                    AuthToken += $"Name: {name}{Environment.NewLine}";
                }

                if (result.Properties.TryGetValue("email", out var email) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                {
                    AuthToken += $"Email: {email}{Environment.NewLine}";
                }
                
                AuthToken += result?.AccessToken ?? result?.IdToken;
                IsAuthenticated = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                AuthToken = string.Empty;
            }
        }
    }
```

Also I have some back-end code. All this works fine, I'm getting access token, UserId and so on.
But I still have some questions.

What is the right way to validate if login is still valid?
How should I authorize app actions?
And how could I implement Logout?

I will be grateful for advices or links.

Answer (score 0):

As a user, you don’t want to have to sign in every time you use the app. Luckily, **MSAL** already caches your authorization and can log you in silently if it’s still valid.When properly authenticated we receive an access token that we can subsequently use to query other APIs that are secured by **MSAL**.

Signing out is pretty straight forward. We go through all the available accounts that **MSAL** has locally cached for us and sign them out. We also clear the access token that we stored in secure storage when we signed in.

```
public async Task<bool> SignOutAsync()
{
  try
  {
    var accounts = await _pca.GetAccountsAsync();

    // Go through all accounts and remove them.
    while (accounts.Any())
    {
        await _pca.RemoveAsync(accounts.FirstOrDefault());
        accounts = await _pca.GetAccountsAsync();
    }

    // Clear our access token from secure storage.
    SecureStorage.Remove("AccessToken");

    return true;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Also I was thinking that MSAL should be used on server side. Do you mean I should use it in my xamarin client app too?

Comment: @Gleb _pca is `PublicClientApplication`, you could refer to [this](https://www.thewissen.io/implementing-msal-authentication-in-xamarin-forms/) and its [sample](https://github.com/sthewissen/MSALSample).

Comment: Is it possible to use MSAL without microsoft account but with facebook and other social networks?

Comment: @Gleb I think you are looking for [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-facebook?pivots=b2c-user-flow).